# Difference between ngBind, ngBindHtm & ngBindTemplate in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, ng-bind-html, ng-bind

I'm new to `Angular JS`.

Can any one of you guys explain me the difference between `ngBind`,`ngBindHtm` & `ngBindTemplate` in `Angular JS` with an example?

Comment: RTFM.  

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBind  

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindHtml  

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngBindTemplate

Comment: I'm confused with what they say in Angular Docs

Answer (score 47, accepted):

#### ng-bind

ngBind is used to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression. For example if you have an html as follows `<b ng-bind="name"></b>` and in your controller give a value for name as `$scope.name = "John"`. This will result in `<b>John</b>`. But you can't use multiple values to bind in a single html element. For example

```
$scope.first_name = "John";
$scope.second_name = "D";
<b ng-bind="first_name second_name"></b>
```

This will not give the result as `<b>John D</b>` **only bind first_name**. So for binding multiple values we can use `ng-bind-template`

#### ng-bind-template

```
 $scope.first_name = "John";
 $scope.second_name = "D";

<b ng-bind-template="{{first_name second_name}}"></b>
```

This results in **`<b>John D</b>`**
But you can't render an html tag in this both. For rendering html template we can use ng-bind-html.

#### ng-bind-html

```
$scope.name = "<b>John</b>";
<div ng-bind-html="name"></div>
```

This will result in ****John**** instead of showing `<b>John</b>` . That means it renders the html instead of showing html tag.

Click this link to view [example](http://plnkr.co/edit/HcRmCyrigRVvLckFJXzN?p=preview)

Comment: <b ng-bind="first_name + '  ' + second_name"></b> is working. We can make ng-bind work like ng-bind-template, but need to do some ugly work. Thats it?

Comment: I see, the real difference is we can use one or more {{ expression }} in ng-bind-template, while in ng-bind we cannot.

Comment: @jilykate You can use it like ng-bind="(person.firstName)+ ' ' +(person.lastName)"

Answer (score 3):

**ngBind :**

The ngBind attribute tells Angular to replace the text content of the specified HTML element with the value of a given expression, and to update the text content when the value of that expression changes.

**ngBindTemplate :**

The ngBindTemplate directive specifies that the element text content should be replaced with the interpolation of the template in the ngBindTemplate attribute. Unlike ngBind, the ngBindTemplate can contain multiple {{ }} expressions. This directive is needed since some HTML elements (such as TITLE and OPTION) cannot contain SPAN elements.
ngBindTemplate only runs "strings"

A simple metaphor for the difference:

**ngBind** only runs "objects".

**ngBindTemplate** only runs "strings"