# The AngularJS's ng-bind-html directive doesn't display correctly unordered list

Tags: angularjs

The code:

```
var appModule = angular.module('lookbookApp',
    [
        'ngSanitize',
    ])

appModule.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
    return function (text) {
        return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
    };
}]);

<div class="text pre-txt" ng-bind-html="caseStudy.Overview | to_trusted"></div>
```

The content of caseStudy.Overview:

```
<ul>
    <li>aaaa</li>
    <li>bbbb</li>
    <li>cccc</li>
    <li>dddd</li>
</ul>
```

The expected output:

```html
<ul>
  <li>aaaa</li>
  <li>bbbb</li>
  <li>cccc</li>
  <li>dddd</li>
</ul>
```

I've read articles on internet devoted to this issue, but my unordered list is still displayed as:

```
   aaaa
   bbbb
   cccc
   dddd
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: What's the content of `caseStudy.Overview`?

Comment: The unordered list above. I've added missing description.

Comment: can you please display what is your expected output?

Comment: For me it's working..

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ebinmanuval/0tLso4vg/3/  |which is your angular version?

Comment: working for me as well

Comment: working for me too

Comment: @Raman Sahasi, Please, take a look at the expected result above.

Comment: My guess is that your text or pre-txt CSS class renders lists without bullets. Inspect the generated HTML code.

Comment: If you want the output to be HTML markup, then you shouldn't use ng-bind-html. ng-bind-html is precisely used to render HTML as HTML-formatted. Use ng-bind (or simply {{ }}): that will escape all the HTML special characters and display the HTML markup. To be clear, if you have a variable containing `<b>hello</b>`, and want to display it as `<b>hello</b>`, than use ng-bin or {{}}. If you want to render it as **hello**, then use ng-bind-html.

Comment: Try something like this to test if `css` is not interfering with your view - `<ul style="list-style: initial !important; ....` If that seems to show the bullets, inspect which `css` is breaking the `ul`

Comment: pre-txt is doing this: .pre-txt {
  white-space: pre-line;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, then you want to render HTML instead of rendered text.

If that's the case, then you shouldn't be using `ng-bind-html`

**ng-bind-html**
`ng-bind-html` renders the html instead of showing html tag.

See the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21086745/2815219).

---

Use this code

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="lookbookApp">

  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
    <div class="text pre-txt" ng-bind="caseStudy.Overview | to_trusted"></div>
    
    <script>
      
      var appModule = angular.module("lookbookApp", ['ngSanitize']);

      appModule.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.test = "Hello World";
        $scope.caseStudy = {};
        $scope.caseStudy.Overview = '<ul><li>aaaa</li><li>bbbb</li><li>cccc</li><li>dddd</li></ul>';
      }]);
      
      
      appModule.filter('to_trusted', ['$sce', function ($sce) {
          return function (text) {
              return $sce.trustAsHtml(text);
          };
      }]);


      
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Output**

```
<ul><li>aaaa</li><li>bbbb</li><li>cccc</li><li>dddd</li></ul>
```

Comment: Please, don't get me wrong, but are you sure that is needed any answer for this question, since there's nothing wrong?

Comment: I need rendered HTML.

Comment: @tesicg see the output, html is only being rendered.

Answer (score -2):

You code works well.

```
$scope.caseStudy = {
    "Overview": "<ul><li>aaaa</li><li>bbbb</li><li>cccc</li><li>dddd</li></ul>"
};
```

Have a look at the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/3h1kb9rz/).