# Show html tags on the page with ng-bind-html

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Please see below given code:

```
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">        
        <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>        
    </div>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
        app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
            $scope.myText = "My name is: <h1>John Doe</h1>";
        });
    </script>
```

The output is: My Name is: 
               **John Doe**

How can i show the text as it is. For example: `My Name is : <h1>John Doe</h1>`
I want to show the HTML tags on the page.

Comment: Try my answer and let me know ?

Comment: [Difference between ngBind, ngBindHtm & ngBindTemplate in Angular JS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21084008/difference-between-ngbind-ngbindhtm-ngbindtemplate-in-angular-js)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please use the `$sce` of `angularjs`.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope, $sce) {
  $scope.myText = $sce.trustAsHtml("My name is: <h1>John Doe</h1>");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller='MyController'>
  <p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
</div>
```

**Reference:**

1. [How to use $sce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18340872/how-do-you-use-sce-trustashtmlstring-to-replicate-ng-bind-html-unsafe-in-angu)

Answer (score 3):

First create a filter using `$sce`:

```
app.filter("html", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(input){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(input);
  }
}]);
```

Then:

```
<div ng-bind-html="myText | html"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ng-bind` instead `ng-bind-html`

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">        
    <p ng-bind="myText"></p>        
</div>
```

Or simply

```
<p>{{myText}}</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use like this

in your controller

```
$scope.mytext="&lth1&gtJohn Doe&lt/h1&gt"
```

in you html page

```
<p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>
```